# Counting sum of items of type

Tags: sql, postgresql

What i what to do is from this :

```
|type|quantity|
+----+--------+
|shoe| 10     |
|hat | 2      |
|shoe| 7      |
|shoe| 1      |
|hat | 5      |
```

to get this :

```
|shoes|hats|
+-----+----+
| 18  | 7  |
```

How can i do that? So far I hadn't come up with a working query, I think it should look something like that:

```
 SELECT 
   SUM(CASE type WHEN 'shoe' then quantity ELSE 0 END) AS "shoes",
   SUM(CASE type WHEN 'hat' then quantity ELSE 0 END) AS "hats"
 FROM items 
 GROUP BY type
```

Comment: Your query is alright, just drop the GROUP BY clause from your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the `group by`.  You want only one row:

```
 SELECT 
   SUM(CASE type WHEN 'shoe' then quantity ELSE 0 END) AS "shoes",
   SUM(CASE type WHEN 'hat' then quantity ELSE 0 END) AS "hats"
 FROM items ;
```